# How to go back to main_thread after Firebase calls its callback function?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase will run in a closure, hence in another thread. I try to call the completion handler when Firebase finishes loading the data.

But I have an error to run it. "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=EXC_1386_GPFLT)" I know the problem is about wrong thread but don't know how to fix it. I am trying to edit the state of a component on the view controller. please help

```
func refreshData(completionHandler:@escaping (Bool)->() ) {
    //I ignore some unrelated statements here
    //....
    //Reloading the database
    ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        var newItems: [Task] = []
        self.num_of_tasks = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
        for item in snapshot.children {
            let taskItem = Task(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot)
            newItems.append(taskItem!)
        }
        let merged = drafts + newItems
        self.items = merged
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        completionHandler(true) //The line causes error
    })
}
```

I call this function in viewDidLoad.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshData),for: .valueChanged)
    self.refreshControl!.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Update the data")
    refreshData{ _ in
        self.refreshControl!.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

Update with Crash log:

```
> * thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x111606db0)
>     frame #0: 0x0000000111606db0 CoreFoundation`__NSSingleObjectArrayI
>     frame #1: 0x000000010f61248a MGSupport`thunk at TaskTableViewController.swift:0   * frame #2: 0x000000010f612294
> MGSupport`TaskTableViewController.(self=0x00007fa6ead25860,
> completionHandler=0x000000010f6124e0 MGSupport`partial apply forwarder
> for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_unowned @convention(block)
> (@unowned ObjectiveC.ObjCBool) -> () to @callee_owned (@unowned
> Swift.Bool) -> () at TaskTableViewController.swift) -> ()) ->
> ()).(closure #1).(closure #1) at TaskTableViewController.swift:95
>     frame #3: 0x000000010f6122d7 MGSupport`thunk at TaskTableViewController.swift:0
>     frame #4: 0x00000001140c94a6 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
>     frame #5: 0x00000001140f205c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
>     frame #6: 0x00000001140d340b libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 411
>     frame #7: 0x0000000111311909 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
>     frame #8: 0x00000001112d7ae4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2164
>     frame #9: 0x00000001112d7016 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
>     frame #10: 0x000000011548ea24 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 62
>     frame #11: 0x0000000111e59134 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
>     frame #12: 0x000000010f62c687 MGSupport`main at AppDelegate.swift:14
>     frame #13: 0x000000011413e65d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Debug udpate: 
I tried to set breakpoint and I found that only the first time the completionHandler can successfully get called when the function is called from viewDidLoad(). But if the user scroll down the screen and invoke the refreshData function again by refreshControl's automatic call, it cannot access the completionHandler anymore. Any idea?

Comment: add the crash log with your question...

Comment: put reloadData and completionHandler into the main.async block call

Comment: @Subramanian I already attach the crash log. Thanks

Comment: can you add `TaskTableViewController.swift:95` line of code..

Comment: @Subramanian The 95 is "completionHandler(true)" in the above code, when I try to call the completion handler.

Comment: Can you add exception break point and give me the line of code where it's crashing. Above completion block don't have any issues related to crash

Comment: @Subramanian I updated my answer. The problem is that it cannot access the completion handler when this function is called by refreshControl. Only the first time when viewDidLoad calls "refreshData" works. Maybe I should put the call-back function somewhere else?

Comment: @Chen Add the solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of `refreshControl` selector. Selector doesn't have any completion handler and when the `refreshControl` values changes that time completion block is trying to execute but there is not completion block for refresh control.

So better give default completion block for your `refreshData(_:)`

```
func refreshData(completionHandler:@escaping (Bool)->() = { _ in }) {
    //You code is here.
}
```

Comment: Yes! I just figured it out. I tried to wrap that function call with completion handler inside another function and it works!

Comment: No need to create separate function for that. you can use one function with default completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try below thing, hope it'll help. also you can check using break point if `self` is available inside closure.

```
 refreshData{ [weak self] _ in
        if let _ = self {
            self?.refreshControl!.endRefreshing()
        } 
    }
```